# Cmake linking to shared library cannot find library

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

On Ubuntu, I have two directories: `build` and `src`. In `src`, my `CMakeLists.txt` file has the lines:

```
add_executable(Test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Test libCamera.so)
```

After running cmake in the build directory (`cmake ../src`), I then copy my library file `libCamera.so` into the build directory. After running make, the `main.cpp.o` file compiles successfully, but I receive the following error during linking:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCamera
```

Why is this? The shared library is in the same directory that I am building in... and the same thing happens if I copy the library to `/usr/bin`...

Answer (score 4):

You should not put prefix `lib` and suffix `.so` of the library, so just use:

```
target_link_libraries(Test Camera)
```

if your library not found you may need to add directory, where library is located:

```
link_directories( /home/user/blah ) # for specific path
link_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ) # if you put library where binary is generated
```

Note: you copied lib to `/usr/bin` but unlike Windows where dll files stored with executables, in Linux that is not the case, so it would be `/usr/lib`, not `/usr/bin`. Also you may change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to make your program to find a library in a custom location.

Comment: If I do that, then I get the same error message as before: `Linking CXX executable Test`, `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCamera`

Comment: I have added the line `link_directories(/home/karnivaurus/Projects/Test/build)` to my CMakeLists.txt file, but I still get the same error.... However, if I copy the library to `/usr/lib`, as you suggested, it compiles fine.... Any idea why the first attempt did not solve it?

Comment: @Karnivaurus btw for `build` you should use cmake var as mentioned above, but full path should still work. Why it does not is difficult to say without looking into actual CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @Karnivaurus note that binary is being buit and linked in build/src subdirectory. If you put lib there you may not need to add that dir. But normally you should not copy library there but use `find_library()` instead